# How can I create my own forms or control class for multi time use?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to create a form where i will set all format like font style, back color, form size one time, and I want to use that form any time in any project.

I will just Import that class, and form will inherit in my project.

Comment: Sure, keep us posted.

Answer (score 0):

A form is just a form, so you create it like you would any other form. Just like any time you want reusable code, you write it in a library project and then reference that library in other projects to use the types it contains.

Create a new project of the appropriate type. If you're targeting .NET Framework, that would be the *Windows Forms Control Library (.NET Framework)* template. If you're targeting .NET Core, which includes .NET 5.0, that would be the *Windows Forms Class Library* or *Windows Forms Control Library*. Whichever one you choose, delete the default type added by the IDE and then create your form exactly as you usually would.

If you're targeting .NET Framework, you can add a new item to your project and choose *Inherited Form*. That will give you the opportunity to navigate to the DLL built from your library project and select the form within it as a base class.

If you're targeting .NET Core, start by adding a reference to the DLL built from the library project or, if you want to debug into it, reference the project itself. Add a form to your application project as you normally would, then open the designer code file and change the base class from `System.Windows.Forms.Form` to your own form in the library.